# python 3.8.16: re.error: bad escape \s at position 0

Tags: python-3.x, regex, anomaly-detection

I am implementing ML model to detect anomaly in log file and it completely work fines on `python2` but i would like to run on `python3` and it gives an error. I tried to replace `import re with import regax as re` and add `\\\s+` but still error is same. The problem is here `splitter = re.sub(' +', '\s+', splitters[k])`

**Code**

```
for k in range(len(splitters)):
    if k % 2 == 0:
        splitter = re.sub(' +', '\s+', splitters[k])
        regex += splitter
    else:
        header = splitters[k].strip('<').strip('>')
        regex += '(?P<%s>.*?)' % header
        headers.append(header)
regex = re.compile('^' + regex + '$')
return headers, regex
```

**Traceback**

```
  File "AEL_demo.py", line 16, in <module>
    parser.parse(log_file)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_24/logparser/demo/../logparser/AEL/AEL.py", line 47, in parse
    self.load_data()
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_24/logparser/demo/../logparser/AEL/AEL.py", line 180, in load_data
    headers, regex = self.generate_logformat_regex(self.logformat)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_24/logparser/demo/../logparser/AEL/AEL.py", line 213, in generate_logformat_regex
    splitter = re.sub(' +', '\s+', splitters[k])
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/logpare/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/logpare/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 327, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/logpare/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 318, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/logpare/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 1042, in parse_template
    raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \s at position 0
```

Comment: The second argument to `re.sub()` is supposed to be the replacement (string, lambda, etc.). What do you mean when you use `\s+`?

Answer (score 0):

to fix this, you can use a raw strind by prefixing 'r' to the replacement string. we have :
splitter = re.sub('r', r'\s+', spliters[k]

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character is special in Python strings; it's an escape character meaning the characters following it need to be examined to determine what the actual string character should be.  For example, `\n` is a single newline character - neither the backslash nor the `n` make it into the final string.

There are quite a few backslash and letter combinations that have a defined meaning, but `\s` isn't one of them.  Python rightly complains that it doesn't quite know what you meant.

If you want to have a backslash in the string you need to double it up - `'\\'`.